# List object occurrence checker python

Tags: python, list

I was working on a small project, and I've run across a little error in my programming. It's a basic battleship game, and so far I have two "ships" set, and I have the game to end when both on either my side or the enemy side is hit.

```
def enemy_board():
global enemy_grid
enemy_grid = []
for i in range (0,10):
    enemy_grid.append(["="] * 10)
def random_row_one(enemy_grid):
    return randint(0, len(enemy_grid) - 1)
def random_col_one(enemy_grid):
    return randint(0, len(enemy_grid) - 1)   
def random_row_two(enemy_grid):
    return randint(0, len(enemy_grid) - 1)
def random_col_two(enemy_grid):
    return randint(0, len(enemy_grid) - 1)
global x_one
x_one = random_row_one(enemy_grid)
global y_one
y_one = random_col_one(enemy_grid)
global x_two
x_two = random_row_two(enemy_grid)
global y_two
y_two = random_col_two(enemy_grid)
print(x_one)
print(y_one)
print(x_two)
print(y_two)
```

So that's the basis of my list, but later on in the code is where it's giving me a little trouble.

```
elif enemy_grid.count("H") == 2:
    print("\nYou got them all!\n")
    break
```

**Update**
Sorry I was a little unclear about what I meant.

```
def my_board():
   global my_grid
    my_grid = []
    for i in range (0,10):
        my_grid.append(["O"] * 10)
        def my_row_one(my_grid):
        int(input("Where do you wish to position your first ship on the x-axis? "))
    def my_col_one(my_grid):
        int(input("Where do you wish to position your first ship on the y-axis? "))
    global x_mio
    x_mio = my_row_one(my_grid)
    global y_mio
    y_mio = my_col_one(my_grid)
    def my_row_two(my_grid):
        int(input("\nWhere do you wish to position your other ship on the x-axis? "))
    def my_col_two(my_grid):
    int(input("Where do you wish to position your other ship on the y-axis? "))
    global x_mit
    x_mit = my_row_two(my_grid)
    global y_mit
    y_mit = my_col_two(my_grid)   
def enemy_board():
    global enemy_grid
    enemy_grid = []
    for i in range (0,10):
        enemy_grid.append(["="] * 10)
    def random_row_one(enemy_grid):
        return randint(0, len(enemy_grid) - 1)
    def random_col_one(enemy_grid):
        return randint(0, len(enemy_grid) - 1)   
    def random_row_two(enemy_grid):
        return randint(0, len(enemy_grid) - 1)
    def random_col_two(enemy_grid):
        return randint(0, len(enemy_grid) - 1)
    global x_one
    x_one = random_row_one(enemy_grid)
    global y_one
    y_one = random_col_one(enemy_grid)
    global x_two
    x_two = random_row_two(enemy_grid)
    global y_two
    y_two = random_col_two(enemy_grid)
    print(x_one)
    print(y_one)
    print(x_two)
    print(y_two)
title()
my_board()
enemy_board()
m = 20
guesses = m
while guesses > 0:      
    def printmi_board(my_grid):
        for row in my_grid:
            print(" ".join(row))
    def printyu_board(enemy_grid):
        for row in enemy_grid:
            print (" ".join(row))
    print(printmi_board(my_grid))
    print(printyu_board(enemy_grid))
    try:
        guess_x = int(input("Take aim at the x-xalue: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("\nI SAID TAKE AIM!\n")
        guess_x = int(input("Take aim at the x-xalue: "))
    try:
        guess_y = int(input("Take aim at the y-value: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("\nDo you have wax in your ears?? AIM!\n")
        guess_y = int(input("Take aim at the y-value: "))
    comp_x = randint(0, len(my_grid) - 1)
    comp_y = randint(0, len(my_grid) - 1)
    if x_one == guess_x and y_one == guess_y:
        print("\nYou hit one! \n")
        enemy_grid[guess_x - 1][guess_y - 1] = "H"
        continue
    elif x_two == guess_x and y_two == guess_y:
        enemy_grid[guess_x - 1][guess_y - 1] = "H"
        print("\nYou hit one! \n")
        continue
    elif enemy_grid[guess_x - 1][guess_y - 1] == "O":
        print("\nYou've tried there before! Here's another round.\n")
        print("You have " + str(guesses) + " rounds left, cadet.\n\n")
        continue
    elif enemy_grid.count("H") == 2:
        print("\nYou got them all!\n")
        break
    else:
        if guess_x not in range(10) or guess_y not in range(10):
            print("\nThat's not even in the OCEAN!! Take another free round then.\n")
            print("You have " + str(guesses) + " rounds left, cadet.\n\n")
            continue
        elif enemy_grid[guess_x][guess_y] == "O":
            print("\nYou've tried there before! Here's another round.\n")
            print("You have " + str(guesses) + " rounds left, cadet.\n\n")
            continue
        else:
            print("\nYou missed, soldier!\n")
            guesses = guesses - 1
            print("You have " + str(guesses) + " rounds left, cadet.\n\n")
            enemy_grid[guess_x - 1][guess_y - 1] = "O"
            if comp_x == x_mio and comp_y == y_mio:
                my_grid[comp_x - 1][comp_y - 1] = "H"
                print("\nThe enemy hit you! \n")
                continue
            elif comp_x == x_mit and comp_y == y_mit:
                my_grid[comp_x - 1][comp_y - 1] = "H"
                print("\nThe enemy hit you! \n")
                continue
            elif my_grid.count("H") == 2:
                print("We have to retreat! They've sunken all of your ships...")
                break
            else:
                my_grid[comp_x - 1][comp_y - 1] = "="
                continue
```

I'm using python 3 if that makes any difference. So it's that if the player hits the correct spot on the grid, then it'll show as "H" and not as "=" or "O". So I was just wondering about if I could count those "H"'s to use to end the IF loop.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: The broken indentation makes the code very difficult to follow. `global` declarations outside functions have no effect. You don't need to define the same function four times with different names (`random_(row/col)_(one/two)`)! Define it just once, and call it four times.

Comment: "_giving me a little trouble_"  What trouble?  Please show the complete error message.

Comment: Sorry one more update, to minimize space in my question, I deleted a definition (title()). So if that's coming up, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't really explained the problem, and so much of the code is missing that it's very hard to tell you what's wrong, I'm going to guess at it though.

My guess is that you create an '=' grid to represent a player's board, and then if their ship is 'hit' you replace the '=' in that position with an 'H'.

The structure you create (enemy_grid) seems to look something like:

```
[[====]
 [====]
 [====]
 [....]]
```

in which case your test, `enemy_grid.count("H")` doesn't make sense as enemy_grid is a list that contains other lists (so the count of Hs will always be 0 - they're deeper down in the 2nd layer of lists).

You probably want a test more along the lines of:

```
[cell for row in enemy_grid for cell in row].count('H')
```

Comment: Thanks! I was just re-thinking my code, and your suggestion was spot on! Sorry I was unable to convey my problem easier, but you got it. I just had to switch where that IF Statement was placed in my code, and with your suggestion, it now works perfectly! Thank you!